# Designing a literal-type class with a variant field inside in which one or three objects may be stored

Tags: c++, c++11, class-design

I'm trying to design a class - let's call it `A` for the sake of discussion - that will fulfill a specific set of requirements:

1. `A` must be a literal type to allow the compiler to initialize its global instances at compile time via `constexpr` constructors (many global `const` objects of this type are created in the source code). The reason for this is that `A` employs simple compile-time encryption (mostly XOR) on the integers. Decryption is later done at runtime while accessing the appropriate `int`.
2. Its central private field is a simple integer. However, the class has two constructors:
   `A::A(int x)` and `A::A(int x, int y, int z)`. If the first version is invoked, then later, at runtime, that single `x` will be used by the class internally whenever a method call that needs to use it is made. In contrast, if the second version with three parameters is used, it will be decided at runtime which one of `x`, `y` and `z` to use if a function that needs one is invoked.
3. `A` must be a single type; one type for the first constructor and another type for the second constructor is not satisfactory (`A` is frequently passed to functions as an argument, so without this constraint, I would need to duplicate or templatize all those functions).
4. A great majority of all `A` objects will be global constants, assignment will seldom happens, and if it does, it will certainly not be between an object with three `int`s and an object with one `int` or vice-versa.

To summarize: `A` will be instantiated as global `const` objects. If I initialize an object with a single `int`, that single `int` should be stored inside it (and nothing more). If I initialize it with three `int`s, then those three `int`s should be stored inside. There's no need to worry about assignment from a three-`int` object to a one-`int` object or vice versa, because they're all constants.

The solutions I have considered so far are as follows:

- Make `A` a template; the template parameter would be what I called the `StorageType`. That storage would abstract access to that central `int` resource by exposing an accessor for it. The problem of choosing which `int` field to use would then be moved from the `A` to this helper storage type. The idea is roughly illustrated by this code:

  ```
  template<typename StorageType>
  class A
  {
  private:
      StorageType storage;

  public:
      constexpr A(int x, int y, int z) :
          storage(x, y, z)
      { }

      constexpr A(int x) :
          storage(x)
      { }

      void doSomething()
      {
          auto theRightInt = storage.getInt();
          // ...
      }
  };
  ```

  **Problem:** violates constraint 3.
- As before, but rather than templatize `A` on the `StorageType`, have a generic interface that describes the `StorageType` and store a `unique_ptr` to one inside `A`.

  **Problem:** violates constraint 1.
- Store the integers as a union:

  ```
  union
  {
      struct
      {
          int x;
          int y;
          int z;
      } intPack;

      int singleInt;
  };
  ```

  In this variant, each `A` object - including those that only use a single `int` - has room for three possible `int`s. Another option would be to use `boost::variant` instead of the obsolete `union`.

  **Problem**: This is wasteful - see point 4. If `boost::variant` is used, it violates constraint 1 since `boost::variant`, unlike `std::variant` from C++17, is not a literal type.
- Rather than attempt to represent the "variance" of the central integer field inside `A`, do it externally: have the class always store a single `int`, and create a helper class - let's call it `VariantA` - that contains three versions of `A`, each initialized with what was `x`, `y` and `z` in the constructor mentioned in point 2. `VariantA` would have an accessor function that decides at runtime which `A` object to return.

  **Problem**: Tedious to use because the accessor has to be invoked every single time:

  ```
  VariantA a1(0, 1, 2);
  VariantA a2(10, 20, 30);

  auto a3 = a1.get() + a2.get();
  someFunctionThatTakesAnA(a1.get());
  // etc
  ```

---

**Question:**
Is there an elegant solution to this problem that I have missed, or will I have to choose one of the solutions I have considered (and rejected) above?
My platform is VC++, so use of C++11/4 is okay except some more esoteric parts, but the features from C++17 drafts are not yet available.

Comment: Why not just use an extra bool member as a flag and initialize it in the constructor as `true` is you use a single `int` and false in the other constructor?

Comment: if the internal is only 3 `int`s, why it's important they are initialized at compile time?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, but in the latter case, where do I store the three ints? At compile time I don't know which one of the three I'll need at runtime.

Comment: @szczurcio Can't `A` just have all 3 variables or are you trying to not waste space?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, that's the problem. See bullet point 3.

Comment: @appleapple See updated answer.

Comment: @szczurcio So [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd6f41baf540f4d5) would not work for you?

Comment: @NathanOliver It would, but like I said in bullet point three, it does waste 8 (usually) bytes for objects where only one `int` will ever be used (like I said, most of these objects are global `const`s). It's not _horrible_, and if I don't find anything better, this is probably what I'll do, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: What does bullet point 2 even mean? Determine which of `x`,`y`,`z` how? Also if you potentially need 3 `int`s and a flag to determine which is used, you can't have less than 3 `int`s worth of storage...

Comment: @Barry Based on external global state (basically a simple `switch` on a global). The thing is that I _do_ know, for each individual object, at compilation time, whether I need three ints or one int. The problem is stuffing all this in a single type and still keeping it literal.

Comment: @szczurcio You have conflicting requirements. You want this type to be able to store 3 `int`s but to not actually store them. The only way to not store them is to have different types.

Comment: @Barry I've added a general summary after the list of my requirements, hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: My impression is that you want to something polymorphic, g without inheritance.  One possible solution would be to have an abstract class and two inherited classes, one for the single int, the other for the int array.  It would probably simplify the rest of your code. - I realize the doesn't satify all of your requirements, but neither does anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the best thing you could use is a conditionally sized range of ints:

```
class A {
    std::array<int, 3> data;
    bool one;

public:
    constexpr A(int x): data{{x, 0, 0}}, one(true) { }
    constexpr A(int x, int y, int z): data{{x, y, z}}, one(false) { }

    constexpr size_t size() const { return one ? 1 : 3; }
    constexpr const int* begin() const { return data.data(); }
    constexpr const int* end() const { return data.data() + size(); }
};
```

I'm not entirely sure what your logic is for selecting which element, but if you have a 1-sized range, you get that element, if you have a 3-sized range, then you do whatever it is you need to do.

---

Regardless of the specific details, the main point is that you want a type that has 3 `int`s and a `bool`. You need to store 3 `int`s, you want it to be literal, and you want it to know whether it's storing 3 or 1 `int`. That pretty much spells out the type. The only thing left is to determine how you want the data access to look, and that's not specified.

Comment: Indeed, it appears this is the best I can do. Always storing all three `int`s results in an excess 12 bytes (in my case) for objects that only ever need to store a single `int` (the flag gets padded), so that's not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

A class/struct with 2 members?

A pointer to `int` and a `bool` (where the boolean say if the pointer point to one or three values)?

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
 {
   bool           single;
   int const    * p;

   constexpr foo ( int const & x ) : single{true}, p{&x}
    {}

   constexpr foo ( int const * y ) : single{false}, p{y}
    {}
 };

constexpr int x{2};
constexpr int y[]{3, 5, 7};

int main ()
 {
   constexpr foo f1{x};
   constexpr foo f3{y};
 }
```

Comment: @szczurcio - yes: it's very, very dangerous: you have to verify that the lifespan of the variable that initialize your `foo()` cover the lifespan of your `foo` object

Comment: Yep, it seems like it does work (tested with VC++ under full optimization now, the objects are initialized at compile time and reside in `.data`). However, this requires the manual allocation of the `int` arguments. Is there a better way?

Comment: @szczurcio - I don't see a better way; your requirments are very hard to satisfy (IMHO).